# Set Theory Proof Verification - Transitivity

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that if $F$ is a partition of the set $A$ and  $$R=\cup_{X\in F}(X\times X)$$ then $R$ is transitive.
Proof:
Suppose $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$. By definition, $(x,y)\in \cup_{X\in F}(X\times X)$ and $(x,y)\in \cup_{X\in F}(X\times X).$ 
Thus, there exists $X_1\in F$ and $X_2\in F$ for which $(x,y)\in X_1\times X_1$ and $(y,z)\in X_2\times X_2$.
By definition of Cartesian Product, $x\in X_1$, $y\in X_1$, $y\in X_2$, and $z\in X_2$.
Since $F$ is a partition and $y\in X_1 \land y\in X_2, \quad X_1 =X_2.$
Hence $(x,z)\in X_1 \times X_1=X_2 \times X_2,$ and so $(x,z)\in \cup_{X\in F}(X\times X),$ meaning $(x,z)\in R.$

Comment: It looks OK to me.

Comment: Did you mean by definition $(x,y)$ and $\color{red}{(y,z)}\in...$